# MATLAB 2015b not reporting monitor position correctly ?

Tags: matlab

I just installed MATLAB 2015b and when I got apparently wrong results when I typed in

```
set(0, 'units', 'pixels')
get(0, 'MonitorPositions')
```

The results I got from 2015b is

```
1        1        1536        864
1537     45.8     1024        819.2
```

And the results I got from 2014b on the same computer is

```
1        1        1920       1080
1921     57       1280       1024
```

The results are correct in MATLAB 2014b but wrong in 2015b. And this is despite updating graphics drivers to the latest version.

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong here and how I can fix it?

Thanks

Comment: So you're getting these outputs using the exact same OS and graphics configuration? Or is the older with the older graphics driver, and the newer with the newer graphics driver?

Comment: You are paying The MathWorks (a lot) for technical support. [Use it](https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/).

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I'm running these two version of MATLAB on the same computer in the exact same OS, same graphics driver ( latest ).

Comment: @excaza, you're right. I just sent a request to Mathworks. I'm still interested in knowing if anyone else has experienced this before, though. There is no similar bug report on Mathworks website.

Comment: @user3667217 [Incorrect values for MonitorPosition and the ScreenSize on dual monitor systems](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/301358). Supposedly fixed in R2014b but potentially re-broken in subsequent releases. Either way, it's clearly an issue for TMW and their customer support is very responsive and generally very knowledgeable.

Comment: Indeed, their customer support is fantastic !

Answer (score 1):

This is the message I received from Mathworks tech support:

"Starting from release R2015b MATLAB takes into account the Windows Setting for "Text and Icon Size" which is otherwise known as the display setting. This impacts the resolution that programs which are display aware since the new resolution will be 1920 / 1.25 = 1536 and 1080/1.25 = 864 for "Medium"(125%) display option. Please note that this does not affect the 'quality' of the figures that are being generated but rather just the 'size in virtual pixels' that MATLAB sees."

So it's not a bug. It's just that MATLAB 2015b is more aware of the environment than 2014b.